# What is the --pretty-print option of Bash 5.0 used for?

Tags: bash

With Bash 5.0:

```
$ bash --help
GNU bash, version 5.0.0(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
    bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
    --debug
    --debugger
    --dump-po-strings
    --dump-strings
    --help
    --init-file
    --login
    --noediting
    --noprofile
    --norc
    --posix
    --pretty-print
    --rcfile
    --restricted
    --verbose
    --version
```

What is this `--pretty-print` option? I can't find it in the Bash 5.0 man page, nor the internet! So mysterious :O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it 8)

In code source, `CWRU/changelog` line 1427:

```
shell.c
    - --pretty-print: new invocation option, currently undocumented, dumps
      a pretty-printed version of a shell script given as an argument to
      stdout
```

I just tried it, it works like `type` with functions but for entire scripts! Neat. Comments will be removed though!

Comment: Define pretty... At first blush, it looks like it strips comments, uses tabs, and joins non-logic, non-definition lines with semi-colons. It strips the shebang, if present. Try: ```diff --color --minimal -w --side-by-side /etc/bash.bashrc <(bash --pretty-print /etc/bash.bashrc )```